# Drag and drop issue with RecyclerView, ItemTouchHelper and GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have found an issue when dragging an item that doesn't trigger a move on a GridLayoutManager with 2 columns.
When dragging one item from the first column to the top of the list (which scrolls the list upwards) and then back to its original position, the recyclerView creates an empty space next to the original position, pushing the item that was next to the dragged item to the next row.

I have coded the simplest app to show you what I mean. On the first screenshot I start dragging one item towards the top of the list. On the second screenshot I reach the top of the screen. Then I move it back to its position and you can already see how the items have not been laid down properly.

Has anyone encountered this as well? I have not found any solution to this issue.

[image: Start drag and drop] [image: Move to the top] [image: Move back to original position]

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val myAdapter = MyAdapter()
    with(findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)) {
        adapter = myAdapter
        layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@MainActivity, 2)
        ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {

            override fun getMovementFlags(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Int {
                return makeFlag(ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG, DOWN or UP or START or END)
            }

            override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun canDropOver(recyclerView: RecyclerView, current: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        }).attachToRecyclerView(this)
    }
    myAdapter.submitList(data)
}


data class ListItem(val id: String, val name: String)

class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

}

class MyAdapter : ListAdapter<ListItem, MyViewHolder>(MyAdapterDiffCallback()) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

    }

    class MyAdapterDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ListItem>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ListItem, newItem: ListItem) = oldItem.id == newItem.id

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ListItem, newItem: ListItem) = oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```